# A help on translating a text in a book for citation

Tags: translation, english-to-german, german-to-english

I am currently writing my High-School Term Paper in Philosophy and want to translate a text from English to German. I study in a Gymnasium in Germany. I am working on my "Facharbeit" (just to let you know what I am working on). I wanted some help on translating the below-mentioned text. Here's the text:

> In Greek, it is called *Politeia*, which means "constitution", and can
>   be understood in the broad sense of the fabric of a society and its
>   ability to reproduce itself and its way of life.

The text is taken from Plato's Republic, Penguin Classics edition (ISBN: 9780140455113)

Here is an image of the page containing the line:
[image]

btw, I apologise in case my question doesn't fit in to this Stackexchange community.

Comment: Wie weit bist Du denn selbst gekommen, mit dem Satz? Wo genau liegt das Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My try:

> Im Griechischen wird es *Politeia* genannt, was Verfassung bedeutet und im weiteren Sinne als das Gesellschaftsgefüge und die Fähigkeit sich selbst und seine Lebensweise zu reproduzieren verstanden werden kann.

Good luck on your Facharbeit!

Comment: "Sich selbst reproduzieren" steht da aber nicht. Ich behaupte, das ist was anderes...

Comment: "Reproduzieren" mag vielleicht eine akzeptable Übersetzung sein, aber im Original bezieht es sich auf die Gesellschaft, und das geht hier etwas verloren, vor allem durch das *seine*. Präziser wäre also *das Gefüge einer Gesellschaft und ihre Fähigkeit, sich selbst und ihre Lebensweise zu reproduzieren*.

Comment: Good point. That brings the point across better.

Comment: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1305/please-do-not-answer-proof-reading-or-translation-requests